# Material-UI: How to add Icons in the TextField label?

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui, label, textfield

I am trying to add Material-UI icons into `TextField` component, I want to add it to the label not in input Field.

Eg:

through `Inputprops` we can pass and add icon to input, but I want it in label. How to achieve this..?

```
<Field label="Name" required /> -> Name*
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
<Field label="Name" required /> -> Name*(icon)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It can be achieved by using [`flex` and `order` properties of CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order), lightweight and effective.**

### Result:

[image] [image]

### Full code sample :

[image: Edit TextField selectionStart]

#### Code fragment :

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "& .MuiFormLabel-root": {
      display: "flex",
      alignItems: "center",
      "& .myIcon": {
        paddingLeft: "8px",
        order: 999
      }
    }
  }
});

const Demo = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <TextField
      className={classes.root}
      required
      label={
        <Fragment>
          I am label
          <SettingsRounded className="myIcon" fontSize="small" />
        </Fragment>
      }
      variant="outlined"
    />
  );
};
```

Hope to help you !

Answer (score 1):

Because `label` can accept a `ReactNode`, you add an icon component to the `TextField` like this:

```js
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Add from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
```

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "& label": {
      marginTop: -3, // fix the icon alignment issue
    }
  },
  label: {
    display: "inline-flex",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
});

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <TextField
      className={classes.root}
      label={
        <div className={classes.label}>
          <span>My Label</span>
          <Add />
        </div>
      }
      variant="outlined"
    />
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67056371/how-to-add-icons-in-material-ui-textfield-label]

Comment: @NearHuscal, thanks for the information but still i want the icon after the required astrisk symbol (*). in your example its before the astrisk

Comment: @Vicky sorry I don't think you can add the icon behind the asterisk, the label component is is always before it.

Comment: Hi @NearHuscarl. Where did you find the code for this Edit on CodeSendbox button in your answer?  This one: 
## Live Demo

[![Edit 67056371/how-to-add-icons-in-material-ui-textfield-label](https://codesandbox.io/static/img/play-codesandbox.svg)](https://codesandbox.io/s/67056371how-to-add-icons-in-material-ui-textfield-label-33rdg?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: @LazarNikolic In your codesandbox, click on the blue Share button at the top > Embed > "Other Sharing Buttons" at the bottom left > Copy the markdown text.

Comment: @NearHuscarl great, thnx. Didn't know about this one.

Comment: @NearHuscarl, thanks for the explanation will try to do it in some other way then.